# Certain tiles from Geoserver's GWC loading too slow

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I have the latest stable release of Geoserver (2.8.2) with Geowebcache and Openlayers 3. I am using the same bounding box as my map's extent. For some reason the upper tiles are extremely slow to load (up to 30 seconds), compared to the rest of the map.  What can be the reason? I am getting no error messages.

Comment: what is in your layer? are there (for example) a lot of roads to draw up there? how are they styled?

Comment: Even though I was using Geowebcache, it seems that uploading the original shape file in the projection it was meant to be shown has removed the problem. But I cannot understand why it was slow to load the tiles, if they were generated in the target projection.